# cygdrive prefix does not work in bash script

Tags: cygwin

/cygdrive/c does not work in my bash script. The lines of code are listed here.

```
PRGPATH="`dirname "$0"`" exec "${PRGPATH}/../../java" .... "${PRGPATH}/xxxx.jar"
```

The result is `Unable to access jarfile /cygdrive/c/app/xxxx.jar`

But if I use `ls /cygdrive/c/app/xxxx.jar`, it is there. And if I replace `/cygdrive/c/` with `c:/` then, the script works.
Why `/cygdrive/c/` does not work in a script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.exe` is a Windows program that requires Windows-style `c:\...` paths in its arguments, not Cygwin-style `/cygdrive/c/...` paths.

Cygwin comes with the [cygpath](http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/using-utils.html#cygpath) utility to convert between the two paths styles.

Try this instead:

```
PRGPATH="`dirname "$0"`" exec "${PRGPATH}/../../java" .... "$(cygpath -w "${PRGPATH}/xxxx.jar")"
```